# Как правильно организовать сайт со своим контентом для разных городов?

Tags: mysql

**На dle cms** пытаюсь организовать автоматическое определение города посетителя сайта.

Столкнулся с главным вопросом, как оптимизировать механизм?
У меня 1117 городов и 90 категорий сайта.

Необходимо в каждом городе - категории, создавать 90 подкатегорий?

Пример:

Москва - авто

Москва - мото

Омск - авто

Омск - мото

Наверное правильно было бы создать отдельную таблицу city и делать выборку контента по city id и category id, но тогда я не вижу механизма реализации сео url, т.е. в url адрес имя города не вписать... можно будет в категории обувь вывести обувь из москвы и обувь из омска, url при этом будет один - obuv

Пожалуйста, объясните, как реализовать города грамотно, не создавая тысячи категорий?

Городов **1117*90=   :-(**

Comment: А с сео, что делать? Я могу добавить город в момент добавления товара, потом делать выборку новостей по городу и категории товара, но url изменяться не будет. С таким механизмом в одной категории можно будет отображать товар разных городов не изменяя url, что плохо.

Comment: Нужно просто добавить город для товара (или что там у вас) и все. Все остается как есть категории не трогаем, они тут не причем, суть же, что в них, так вот то, что в них - это товары (объявления и т. д.), к ним и добавляем колонку город, в городе котором будете находиться будут эти товары в конкретно созданной категории при создании товара.

Comment: Про `url` не понял, что значит: `но url изменяться не будет.`? Сео, опять-же, тут не причем. Для сео вы можете сделать карту сайта с нужными ссылками.  Да и не понятно, ну не меняется,сделайте, чтобы менялся =) В чем проблема? (`/city1/product1`, `/city1/product2` `/city2/product3`) Меняется же? Или что вам нужно тогда?

Comment: Теперь понятнее стало. Создаю таблицу с городами, далее при добавлении товаров указываю город и категорию товара. Потом открываю город и вижу его товары. Но как это реализовать в dle cms, по дефолту там только категории. Т.е. сейчас site.ru/category1/product, а нужно site.ru/moscow/category1/product

Comment: В `.htaccess` добавить в адреса город, в форме по созданию товара добавить город, в таблицу по товарам, добавить город.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто создать в таблице каждого города столбец, отвечающий за категорию.

Comment: 1117*90? Но ведь автор написал, что это _":-("_. Или я неправильно Вас понимаю?